# Copy and overwrite files between two folders(one shared)

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I'm making a small application that have to take all the files from a shared folder and copy them in the current folder(the once from where the application it's runned).
One month ago this code was fine:

```
            string seprin_address = @"\\PC-SEPRIN\2port\";
            SimpleCopy(seprin_address);

    public void SimpleCopy(string sourcePath){
    try{
        string fileName = ""; 
        string targetPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        bool path = false;
        string real_target = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < targetPath.Length; i++){
            if(targetPath[i] == 'C'){
                path = true;
            }
            if(path){
                real_target += targetPath[i];
            }
        }
        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths. 
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);


        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location: 
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
        /*if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        }*/

        // To copy a file to another location and  
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        //System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

        // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory. 
        // Get the files in the source folder. (To recursively iterate through 
        // all subfolders under the current directory, see 
        // "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.")
        // Note: Check for target path was performed previously 
        //       in this code example. 
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName); 

                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }

        // Keep console window open in debug mode.
        }
        catch(Exception e_p){
            lbabel.Text = e_p.Message;
        }
    }
```

Now i get the "URI not supported error" when the file.copy it's called.
I think its supernatural but if you have any other ideas i'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I would find out if the URI not supported is complaining about source or destination.  I would also check to make sure the user that this is running as has permission to the directories in question.  Could the users permissions have changed?  I have had occasion where I had jobs in scheduled tasks where the user was set and later the password was changed for the user but not on the scheduled task.  The same could be true if this is written as a service with a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

as you are saying it was working fine one month ago,  there can be two possibilities which is restricting you from accessing the Path.

1.Remote PC `Hostname` `PC-SEPRIN` might havebeen changed.Please check the remote pc hostname.
2.check the Shared Folder `2port` path properly.

if somebody changes shared folder name or deletes it, you can not access it.
and also please check whether you have permissions to access it or not.